# How can I implement Apply button functionality in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I implement Apply button action in a Windows Forms dialog with C#?

Comment: Could you describe what you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Forms doesn't make it particularly easy unless it is the dialog itself that takes care of the side-effects.  Which isn't always common, it is usually done in the form that calls ShowDialog(), based on the return value.

No biggie though, add your own event to the form:

```
    public event EventHandler ApplyChanges;
    protected virtual void OnApplyChanges(EventArgs e) {
        var handler = ApplyChanges;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        OnApplyChanges(EventArgs.Empty);
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void ApplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        OnApplyChanges(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

And the code in your main form could then look like this:

```
    private void ShowOptionsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (var dlg = new Form2()) {
            dlg.ApplyChanges += new EventHandler(dlg_ApplyChanges);
            dlg.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }

    void dlg_ApplyChanges(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var dlg = (Form2)sender;
        // etc..
    }
```

Comment: +1 Good point about it not usually being the dialog itself that's responsible for its side-effects. This is probably the more elegant solution if your situation is not as simplistic as I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [AcceptButton-Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) of a Form to any button placed on the form. When the "Enter" key is pressed on the form, the Click-Event of the AcceptButton is raised.

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**In Windows, the "Apply" button generally sets whatever properties that the user has specified in the dialog *without* closing the dialog box.** So it's basically the same thing as the "OK" button, except without a command to close the dialog box.

You can take advantage of that fact and consolidate all of the property-setting code in the event handler for the Apply button, then call that first whenever the OK button is clicked, but before you close the form:

```
public void ApplyButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Set any properties that were changed in the dialog box here
    //...
}

public void OKButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //"Click" the Apply button, to apply any properties that were changed
    ApplyButton.PerformClick();

    //Close the dialog
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```